# timeout: ping3 сразу отдает значение false

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

помогите с ping3, задаю параметр timeout=20:

```
from ping3 import ping
otvet =  ping('10.200.231.203', timeout=20, ttl=20)
print(otvet)
```

Если ответ приходит ***Ответ от 10.8.8.150: Заданный узел недоступен***, то значение otvet становится False сразу.

```
Ответ от 10.200.231.203: число байт=32 время=94мс TTL=62
Ответ от 10.200.231.203: число байт=32 время=86мс TTL=62
Ответ от 10.200.231.203: число байт=32 время=82мс TTL=62
Ответ от 10.200.231.203: число байт=32 время=103мс TTL=62
Ответ от 10.200.231.203: число байт=32 время=87мс TTL=62
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Ответ от 10.8.8.150: Заданный узел недоступен.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Ответ от 10.8.8.150: Заданный узел недоступен.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
```

Как сделать, если полноценного ответа не приходит, то он пытается достучаться в любом случае до него в течении 20 секунд?

**Существующий цикл, в котором хотелось бы использовать цикл исключения:**

```
def ping_complexes(row_size):
    try:
        records = Mangustes.query.limit(row_size).all()
        for record in records:
            if ping(record.ip, timeout=20, ttl=3) in (None, False):
                print('Offline: '+record.ip)
                record.Status = 'Offline'
            else:
                print('Online: ', record.ip)
                record.Status = 'Online'
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("???", e)
```

Попытка с доп. функцией:

```
def ping_complexes(row_size):
    try:
        records = Mangustes.query.limit(row_size).all()
        for record in records:
            if pinger in (None, False):
                print('Offline: '+record.ip)
                record.Status = 'Offline'
            else:
                print('Online: ', record.ip)
                record.Status = 'Online'
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("???", e)

def pinger():
    while (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() < timeout:
        otvet = ping(record.ip, timeout=timeout)
        if otvet:
            break
    return(otvet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вам набросал решение:

```py
from ping3 import ping
import datetime

timeout = 20
start = datetime.datetime.now()
while (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() < timeout:
    otvet =  ping('10.200.231.203', timeout=timeout, ttl=20)
    if otvet: # завершаем в случае успеха
        break
print(otvet)
```

Этот код делает то, что вы хотите. Хотя смысла в этом, мне кажется, не много. Дело в том, что параметр `timeout` у `ping` задаёт **максимальное время ожидания ответа на запрос**. Смысл в том, что если сигнал где-то там долго плутает, чтобы не ждать его бесконечно. В случае же, если наблюдается явная ошибка - например, задан некорректный адрес для пинга или есть проблемы с конфигурацией сети, то ждать тут пингу нечего - ответ уже сразу есть, что мы имеем какую-то ошибку с сетью, понятие таймаута тут никак не применимо. Поэтому в такой ситуации можно только организовать внешний цикл, который будет ожидать либо положительного ответа либо окончания отведённого на запрос времени. Что я и делаю в этом коде. Если сеть бывает падает и через какое-то время поднимается и вы не хотите видеть этого события в результатах работы пинга, а хотите просто переждать этот момент, то этот код вам может помочь. В остальных случаях мне кажется нет смысла ждать чего-то в случае явной ошибки сети.

**Update:**
Если у вас просто есть отдельные выпадения пинга и вы хотите пропустить ошибку (но не более скольки-то раз), то можно просто сделать какое-то число попыток без учёта времени работы кода, это будет проще:

```py
from ping3 import ping

for _ in range(5):
    otvet = ping('10.200.231.203', timeout=20, ttl=20)
    if not (otvet == False): # завершаем если успех или таймаут
        break
print(otvet)
```

Вообще стандартный пинг позволяет задать число попыток и тут бы оно пригодилось, но в данной конкретной библиотеке похоже нет такой возможности, я такого параметра не нашёл.

Comment: здравствуйте! Такая нужда появилась из-за того, что есть оборудование которое работает по GSM и бывает, что пинги иногда пропадают, но на работоспособность это не влияет, и это хочется игнорировать. В случае если 20 секунд ни одного пинга не проходит - то это уже проблема с сетью на самом деле) Спасибо большое за решение, сейчас испытаю его!

Comment: Ваш цикл работает отдельно, но попытался я использовать ваш цикл в своем, у меня к сожалению ничего не получилось, свой цикл я добавил в конце своего вопроса, не могли бы Вы помочь совместить их в один цикл?

Comment: Вынесите мой код в отдельную функцию и вызывайте её там, где сейчас вызываете ping. Если не получится, я позже напишу как

Comment: вынес код в функцию, но с return мне кажется, что накосячил.  ping_complexes выдает, что все адреса онлайн, хотя это не так. Код прикрепил в конце вопроса.

Comment: Так вы не вызываете функцию ;) И аргументы надо передавать в неё. Как только сделаете вызов сразу ошибки вылезут

Comment: попробовал, но получилось видимо ерунда) Ошибка: ??? name 'record' is not defined

Comment: `def pinger(ip, timeout)` - аргументы в явном виде. Вызов `pinger(record.ip, timeout)`

Comment: после первого неактивного IP выдал: ??? local variable 'otvet' referenced before assignment

Comment: Попробовал перед функцией pinger задать переменную otvet = '', а после функции описал otvet = pinger(otvet), но тоже выдает ошибку. Думал, что это из-за глобальной переменной и хотел обойти ее так

Comment: Здесь тоже напишу. Строка `start = datetime.datetime.now()` должна начинать функцию `pinger`. Ведь отсчёт должен начинаться со стартом этой функции. Из-за того, что вы вынесли эту строку наружу у вас с какого-то момента `while` перестаёт срабатывать и переменная `otvet` остаётся не инициализированной.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь дошло, чем переменная вне функции отличается с переменной внутри функции. Ту тему удалил, дабы не плодить однообразие. Спасибо за комментарии к ответу =)

Comment: Так то вы всё правильно делаете, по идее так и надо на будущее - задавать новый отдельный вопрос, если возникает дополнительный вопрос сверх рамок текущего. Но и удалили тоже правильно, потому что в данном случае лучше всё решить в рамках текущего вопроса, вне этого контекста вряд ли кому тот вопрос пригодился бы потом )